# How to reinstall recently removed softwares?

Tags: software-installation

While installing some softwares, the system removed several softwares automatically. And I also found out newly installed softwares are almost useless to me. So I want to revert to the last state(that is, remove the newly installed softwares and install the recently removed softwares). Because there are many softwares in question, so I don't want to do it one by one. Is there any method to do the trick conveniently?

Comment: Are you in need of knowing what got removed as well?

Comment: @Rinzwind No, I've already found them in Ubuntu Software Center and /var/log/dpkg.log. I just want a quick way to remove and install them. Thank you.

Comment: `apt-get install ubuntu-desktop` is going to pull most of the defaults. Otherwise we need more information on what you installed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the below:

```
cat /var/log/apt/history.log | grep 'apt-get remove' | cut -d" " -f4 | xargs apt-get install
```

What it does is, list all the packages that have been removed using '`apt-get remove`' and then attempts to install them one by one.  You might also want to rerun this using '`purge`' instead of '`remove`'.

**Note** that, this will install ALL applications you have removed so far, not just the recent ones.  You can edit the history.log file to remove old entries and keep only the "recent" ones